# Is there an app that would detect my over- or under-optimization errors in my unpublished article?

Tags: seo, wordpress, ranking, google-ranking, yoast

I know of Website Auditor, SEO Spyglass, Rank Tracker, and Link Assistant - I downloaded them all. But Website Auditor is only good for keywords, Rank Tracker only works on published articles, the other two I don't understand.

I've been having some problems lately with my supervisor because I'm always either under-optimizing or over-optimizing. I tried so many things: borrowing elements from the headings of top results, counting the number of occurrences of a keyword, internal linking... I also always take the Yoast SEO under the wordpress seriously - I make sure to have a Good score on both SEO and readability. I badly need to learn, but "having a feel" for whether or not the article has good SEO or not is not my strong suit.

I believe with Rank Tracker I can gauge where I went wrong on my published article. BUT, my supervisor does not allow me to publish the articles yet. I am so screwed. Please suggest apps other than Yoast, since it doesn't really work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I started where you are now, looking for the "magic tool" or special trick to rank.

I'm not familiar with the tools you mentioned other than Yoast, but even some of the most popular tools use outdated techniques from 10 years ago,  which can leave you wasting time doing things that don't matter.

Good SEO has way too many factors for one application to solve everything.  Spend lots of time reading posts here, and I think you'll get far more than most of the tools you find.  The more knowledgeable you become about SEO, the better you can use the tools and know what things are worth improving and what is a waste of time.

Lastly, I think your supervisor might be a little too short sighted.  Google constantly reviews pages.  It's unrealistic to think any page will rank #1 when initially published.  Instead, publish your pages and watch them in Google Analytics for a few months (not days or weeks), to see how they perform.  Using GA and what you learn here, you'll get a better idea of how to improve your SEO.  Even if you hired an SEO company, they probably wouldn't be able to position your pages on the first page of Google for a few months.

Yoast is good, and I use it, but I would recommend you read the following posts here in conjunction with Yoast:

[SEO: Where do I start?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/22877/seo-where-do-i-start)

[What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google)

[Very low CTR in google organic results](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/44327/very-low-ctr-in-google-organic-results)